# How to get local images dynamically from .json file in React-native

Tags: json, react-native

I have json file named "Bread.json" following is the content of the file.

How to use image name dynamically in `<Image>`

I'm trying following but getting error. I'm getting image name's array from json file into the `Flatlist`, so `{item.img} = my image name from json file`. But not working!

```
<Image source={require('../images/'+{item.img})} />
```

So, how can I use image name in source of the `<Image>`, Also I can not use `require()` function into my json file. Any help?

"bread.json"

```
[
  {
    "id": "1",
    "img": "1.jpg",
    "cat": "Breakfast",
    "title": "Small Semolina Griddle Breads"
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "img": "2.jpg",
    "cat": "Side",
    "title": "Corn Bread"
  },
  {
    "id": "3",
    "img": "3.jpg",
    "cat": "Appetizer",
    "title": "Fresh Tomato Bruschetta"
  }
﻿]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this!

```js
<Image source={getImageSource(item.img)} />


function getImageSource(image) {

    let imageSrc = require('../images/logo.png');

    switch (image) {
        case "1.jpg":
            imageSrc = require('../images/1.jpg');
            break;

        default:
            break;

    }
    return imageSrc;
}
```

Comment: Good solution but actually I have 2085 JSON objects, so that I have 2085 images in my JSON file, so I can't use switch-case

Comment: Try this

function getImageSource(image) {

    let imageSrc = require(`\`../images/${image}\``);

    return imageSrc;
}

Comment: Getting response error code: 500 error, here's my code `<Image source={this.getImageSource(item.img)} />` and the function as you mentioned  `getImageSource(image) {
        console.log("My_Image",image);

        let imageSrc = require(\`../images/${image}\`);
        return imageSrc;
    }`

Comment: But if I use static image path like this `let imageSrc = require(\`../images/1.jpg\`);` it works, It means there is no syntax error in above code. So I guess it won't work.

Comment: function getImageSource(image) { 
let URL = `\`../images/${image}\``;
let imageSrc = require(URL); 
return imageSrc; }

Comment: not working dude, getting the same error "server returned response error code: 500 (invalid call at line: 261)"

Comment: here's the code: `getImageSource(image) {
        console.log("My_Image", image);

        let URL = \`../images/${image}\`;
        let imageSrc = require(URL);
        return imageSrc;
    }` line 261 = `let imageSrc = require(URL);`

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps!

1) Create a file (to hold JSON data) e.g bread.js:

```js
const Breads=[
  {
    "id": "1",
    "img" : require('../images/1.jpg'),
    "cat": "Breakfast",
    "title": "Small Semolina Griddle Breads"
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "img" : require('../images/2.jpg'),
    "cat": "Side",
    "title": "Corn Bread"
  },
  {
    "id": "3",
    "img" : require('../images/3.jpg'),
    "cat": "Appetizer",
    "title": "Fresh Tomato Bruschetta"
  }
]
export default Breads;
```

2) Then import the data in component and loop through the list using a FlatList

```html
import Breads from './bread.js';

<FlatList 
 data={Breads}
 keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.id}
 renderItem={({item}) => <View>
                            <Image source={item.src} />
                            <Text>{item.title}</Text>
                         </View>
   }
/>
```

Comment: Yeah, I have already done this with putting whole data in a .js file, and it's working but problem is I had to rename the all image names by putting require() function. So this is the solution which works. But is there any way to get images directly from .json file?